# How to dialog not close when onClick

Tags: android, dialog

I have an activity that is using dialog. However, when I click dialog, control values and the dialog closes. How can dialog not close when click dialog?

```java
private Dialog ekleDialog(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View layout = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_ekle, null);

    builder.setTitle(R.string.ekleAction);
    builder.setView(layout);

    final EditText tutarEdit = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editTextTutar);
    final EditText aciklamaEdit = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editTextAciklama);

    final RadioButton gelirRadio = (RadioButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.radioGelir);
    final RadioButton giderRadio = (RadioButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.radioGider);

    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialogCancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            removeDialog(EKLE);

        }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialogKaydet, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            float tutar = Float.parseFloat(tutarEdit.getText().toString());
            String aciklama = aciklamaEdit.getText().toString();  

                if(tutarEdit.getText().toString().equals("") || aciklamaEdit.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.toastMesaj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                **Dialog not close !**      
                }else{
                    ekleGelir(tutar, aciklama);
                    removeDialog(EKLE);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
    });

    builder.setCancelable(true);
    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a guess here, but it probably has to do with:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            removeDialog(EKLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one code path which does not dimiss the dialog at all. Try changing it o

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        float tutar = Float.parseFloat(tutarEdit.getText().toString());
        String aciklama = aciklamaEdit.getText().toString();  

        if(tutarEdit.getText().toString().equals("") || aciklamaEdit.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.toastMesaj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
                ekleGelir(tutar, aciklama);
                removeDialog(EKLE);
        }            
        dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, not dosn't

Comment: also add dialog.dismiss() to your negative button onClick()